# How to use RoundedBitmapDrawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap

Has anyone managed to use `RoundedBitmapDrawable`? Correct me if I'm wrong, but to my understanding, it makes a circular image from a regular rectangular image.

What I've tried so far is this

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable.createRoundedBitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), iconResource))
```

What I tried to achieve: transform any image to a circular image and show it using an ImageView.

In case I mixed things up and all that I said is non-sense. Is it possible (or simpler) to do it with any of the new framework? (Android L or new Support Library)

Comment: What you are getting with this?

Comment: Original image (square image)

Comment: I think you have to use third party library.

Comment: check https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView api

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You need to set the corner radius.

```
Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, iconResource);
RoundedBitmapDrawable dr =
    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, src);
dr.setCornerRadius(Math.max(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
imageView.setImageDrawable(dr);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I found that method too. Just one question, why Math.max and getHeight/getwitdth /2; and not `dr.setCornerRadius(Math.min(dr.getMinimumWidth(),dr.getMinimumHeight`?

Comment: You're right, that's better. I think they might actually return the same result due to RoundedBitmapDrawable constraining the corner radius. Just passing in the width or height would probably work, as well.

Comment: RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory only has a "create()" function and not "createRoundedBitmapDrawable", both get the same parameters, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There is `dr.setCircular(true)`

Comment: toolbar logo doesnt accept `RoundedBitmapDrawable` so how do i get rounded bitmap from this? `getBitmap` returns the original bitmap

Comment: What about non-square images as input? According to what I see, the output is stretched in this case. Any way to use center crop?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the code from my 2014 comment `dr.setCornerRadius(Math.min(dr.getMinimumWidth(), dr.getMinimumHeight()) / 2.0f)` achieved exactly that: crop and make a non-streched circle (based on min side of the rectangle)

Answer (score 70):

It may be a late reply but i hope that it will be helpful to others

If your image has same width and height then you can simply set the setCircular to true to get Rounded Bitmap as follows

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(),your_bitmap);
drawable.setCircular(true);
```

Comment: Simple, brilliant!

Comment: toolbar logo doesnt accept `RoundedBitmapDrawable` so how do i get rounded bitmap from this? `getBitmap` returns the original bitmap

Comment: When the input image is not square (a long rectangle, for example), the output circular image content is stretched inside. Is there any way to achieve a center-crop mechanism for this?

Answer (score 9):

i am also finding rounded image view  for efficiency i have search all third party library i found that all of them they are creating new bitmap which is tedious task in list its consuming more memory

refereed library:

1. http://ruibm.com/2009/06/16/rounded-corner-bitmaps-on-android/
2. https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView
3. https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

from this library i have used

> https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

because 
A fast ImageView (and Drawable) that supports rounded corners (and ovals or circles) based on the original example from Romain Guy

- does not create a copy of the original bitmap
- does not use a clipPath which is not hardware accelerated and not anti-aliased.
- does not use setXfermode to clip the bitmap and draw twice to the canvas.

Answer (score 7):

Full code:

```
ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageid);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.yourpictureresource);

RoundedBitmapDrawable rnd = (RoundedBitmapDrawable) RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap);
rnd.setCircular(true);
img.setImageDrawable(rnd);
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a Utility class to create RoundedBitmapDrawables
https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/a91fb0ce40f083073d4b8939281b3ecb

It works for circles and rounded squares.

```
public class RoundedBitmapDrawableUtility {

    public static RoundedBitmapDrawable getRoundedSquareBitmapDrawable(Context context, Bitmap originalBitmap, int cornerRadius){
        return getRoundedSquareBitmapDrawable(context, originalBitmap, cornerRadius, -1, -1);
    }


    public static RoundedBitmapDrawable getRoundedSquareBitmapDrawable(Context context, Bitmap originalBitmap, int cornerRadius, int borderWidth, int borderColor){
        int originalBitmapWidth = originalBitmap.getWidth();
        int originalBitmapHeight = originalBitmap.getHeight();

        if(borderWidth != -1 && borderColor != -1){
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(originalBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            Paint borderPaint = new Paint();
            borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
            borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            borderPaint.setColor(borderColor);

            int roundedRectDelta = (borderWidth/3);
            RectF rectF = new RectF(0 + roundedRectDelta, 0 + roundedRectDelta, originalBitmapWidth - roundedRectDelta, originalBitmapHeight - roundedRectDelta);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, borderPaint);
        }

        RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedImageBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), originalBitmap);
        roundedImageBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
        roundedImageBitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true);
        return roundedImageBitmapDrawable;
    }

    public static RoundedBitmapDrawable getCircleBitmapDrawable(Context context, Bitmap originalBitmap){
        return getCircleBitmapDrawable(context, originalBitmap, -1, -1);
    }

    public static RoundedBitmapDrawable getCircleBitmapDrawable(Context context, Bitmap originalBitmap, int borderWidth, int borderColor){
        if(borderWidth != -1 && borderColor != -1) {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(originalBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            Paint borderPaint = new Paint();
            borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
            borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            borderPaint.setColor(borderColor);

            int circleDelta = (borderWidth / 2) - DisplayUtility.dp2px(context, 1);
            int radius = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - circleDelta;
            canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, radius, borderPaint);
        }

        RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedImageBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), originalBitmap);
        roundedImageBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
        roundedImageBitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true);
        return roundedImageBitmapDrawable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest another option:

you can use this method in order to scale it according to your needs and avoid this Exception:

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmapAndKeepRation(Bitmap TargetBmp, int reqHeightInPixels, int reqWidthInPixels) {
        if (TargetBmp != null) {

            if (TargetBmp.getWidth() >= TargetBmp.getHeight()) {

                TargetBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        TargetBmp,
                        TargetBmp.getWidth() / 2 - TargetBmp.getHeight() / 2,
                        0,
                        TargetBmp.getHeight(),
                        TargetBmp.getHeight()
                );

            } else {

                TargetBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        TargetBmp,
                        0,
                        TargetBmp.getHeight() / 2 - TargetBmp.getWidth() / 2,
                        TargetBmp.getWidth(),
                        TargetBmp.getWidth()
                );
            }

            if (TargetBmp != null) {
                try {
                    Matrix m = new Matrix();
                    m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, TargetBmp.getWidth(), TargetBmp.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, reqWidthInPixels, reqHeightInPixels), Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
                    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(TargetBmp, 0, 0, TargetBmp.getWidth(), TargetBmp.getHeight(), m, true);
                    return scaledBitmap;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Utils", e.toString());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The current way RoundedBitmapDrawable works on non-square images is not so well. It makes the content stretch.

I suggest using an alternative for this, as I've written here:
[How to have a circular, center-cropped imageView, without creating a new bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35481807/878126)

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you have imagePath instead of bitmap, you can pass imagePath like below:

```
// set round image
RoundedBitmapDrawable dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), avatarImgPath);
dr.setCircular(true);
avatarImageView.setImageDrawable(dr);
```